# Wear OS Complication setTapAction(): No Broadcast

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-complication

I'm creating a pending intent for complication tap like this:

```
    override fun onComplicationRequest(request: ComplicationRequest, listener: ComplicationRequestListener )  {

        class ComplicationBroadcastListener : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                Log.i(tag,"ComplicationBroadcastListener.onReceive()")
            }
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, ComplicationBroadcastListener::class.java)
        complicationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, request.complicationInstanceId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        ...
```

I'm registering it with the complication like this:

```
    private fun createComplicationData(value: Float, absString: String, sense: String) =
        RangedValueComplicationData.Builder(
           ...
        ).setTapAction(
            complicationPendingIntent
        ).build()
```

`complicationPendingIntent` is definitely being initialised before the call to `setTapAction`, but `onReceive` is never called.

I know the structure of this code is poor; I'm just trying to simplify things in case `this` or `context` mean different things in different places.

Everything else with my project is working; eg, I can get the complication to update on schedule or on receipt of new data.

I'm aware of [Exposing data to watch face complications on Wear OS](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/data-sources#0), and my code was originally based on that. I can't get the code in that repo to work either.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver needs to be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In my case, the final version is:

```
<receiver android:name=".complication.ComplicationBroadcastListener" />
```